# Adding additional parameters to data constructors using infix operators

Tags: parsing, haskell, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

I have written a data constructor like

`data Expr = IntL Integer | Expr :*: Expr`

and would like to annotate it with extra constructor parameters (such as positional information) like this:

`data Expr = IntL Integer Pos | Expr :*: Expr Pos`

However GHC does not like this:

```
Expected kind '* -> *' but 'Expr' has kind '*' 
In the type 'Expr Position'
In the definition of data constructor ':*:'
In the data declaration for 'Expr'
```

I know I could use something like `Mul Expr Expr Pos` as a work around or even wrap `Expr` in another data constructor, but I'd really like to use the infix operator and cannot figure a way to do so! Is this possible?

I've tried wrapping the constructor in brackets:

`data Expr = IntL Integer Pos | (Expr :*: Expr) Pos`

And also making :*: a prefix:

`data Expr = IntL Integer Pos | (:*:) Expr Expr Pos`

but this does not allow me to pattern match in the same way. I'm not sure this even makes sense as a type constructor but thought I'd ask just in case.

Comment: `data Expr = IntL Integer Pos | Expr :*: Expr Pos` is read as `data Expr = IntL Integer Pos | Expr :*: (Expr Pos)` but regardless, how would that look when you used that?

Comment: `:*:` could have been defined as `(:*:) Expr Expr`. Something like `(:*:) Expr Expr Pos` would be illegal, because you can't define infix ternary operators. Expressions are one-dimensional; you can put an operand before an operator and/or after an operator. There's no "top", "bottom", "front", "back", etc operands available.

Comment: @chepner `(:*:) Expr Expr Pos` _is_ legal, only it's silly to use, largely defeating the point of using an infix. In particular, it makes it impossible to use the operator as an infix in pattern matches, albeit not in expressions: `(x:*:y) z`.

Comment: Ah, I should have tried it. I assumed, since `:`-prefixed constructors are reserved for infix operators, that it would be syntactically limited.

Answer (score 3):

It might be better to do this with an extra constructor, so:

```
infixl 6 :*:
infixl 7 :@
data Expr = IntL Integer | PosExpr :*: PosExpr
data PosExpr = Expr :@ Pos
```

Then you can construct items with:

```
(IntL 5 :@ foo :*: IntL 6 :@ bar) :@ qux
```

Comment: I those pragmas valid, do you mean `infixl 6 :*:` without the brackets?

Comment: @Iceland_jack: aaarrrggghhh... sorry, fixed!

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was a new feature in the language!